# Who is the real songwriter of a song?

Tags: lyrics, music-business, copyright, songwriter

When I Google a song lyrics, Google usually shows it with songwriters at the bottom. For instance, "**post malone paranoid lyrics**"

[image]

Is it possible to find out who took what part in songwriting process? Who created lyrics, who created music, who produced, etc.

Comment: I suspect only possible for individual songs, and that only by further research.

Answer (score 2):

The roles are very often not clearly divided within the team, often the lyrics and the music are a collaborative effort. The producer would not usually get a songwriting credit unless they did contribute to either lyrics or music, although it's possible that the producer or other people in the team might insist on a credit, even if they didn't contribute to the songwriting. The album cover or booklet might have a more detailed breakdown on who contributed what.

Comment: Or, famously, Lennon/McCartney were credited no matter which one of them wrote the song.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re a musician/publisher and have registered to be a member of PRS for Music (or perhaps another copyright society), you can search their musical works database.

You can search for a specific track (if it’s covered by copyright) and the database will tell you who was Author, Composer/Author or Arranger.